# How to generate oauth_signature in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, postman, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to call an API which was associated with OAuth 1.0 version. From the postman wen I tried by passing the header param "Authorization" It's value is as follows :

```
OAuth realm="realm1",
oauth_consumer_key="oauth_consumer_key1",
oauth_token="oauth_token1",
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA256",
oauth_timestamp="1607936624",
oauth_nonce="vWZBL6a34T",
oauth_version="1.0",
oauth_signature="0md4Tg9wqa4DZV9VGwtvwPeb0ojZoRr0j6pR00HTu1I%3D"
```

From the above key value pairs:

```
oauth_signature
oauth_timestamp
oauth_nonce
```

These 3 are generating dynamically, Which I had observed in postman.
How can I generate these 3 in C# code dynamically ?

Comment: try to use lib provided by microsoft,

Comment: @phonemyatt From nuget what I needs to install ?

Comment: u can try oauth.net, or owin

Comment: @phonemyatt If possible can you please provide me any documentation link on that ?

Comment: i think you can refer to this link first. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.owin.security.jwt.jwtbearerauthenticationoptions?view=owin-4.1. some of those are autogenerated, so if you want to generate dynamically, you need to encode yourself. try to search for HMAC-SHA256 encoding for token

Answer (score -1):

You can use [OAuth library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OAuth.DotNetCore/) to generate authorization header.

```
OAuthRequest client = OAuthRequest.ForProtectedResource("HTTP_METHOD", "CONSUMER_KEY", "CONSUMER_SECRET", "ACCESS_TOKEN", "ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET");
client.RequestUrl = "REQUEST_URL";

string auth = client.GetAuthorizationHeader();
```

Comment: this doesn't answer OPs question.  he asked about generating the oauth signature programatically.  you replied showing him how to request a token, but generating oauth signatures is something that happens after the token has not only been requested but already authorized.